# Entity Framework Core 6 - related entities loaded by default without use Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API application with Entity Framework Core. I have entities `AssetsCategoryMaster` and `Users`. `AssetsCategoryMaster` has a reference navigation property for `Users` (`CreatedBy`) and `Users` has a collection navigation property for `AssetsCategoryMaster` (`AssetsCategoryCreatedList`).

I just query `AssetsCategory` as shown here:

```
var AssetCategoryList = await _context.Set<AssetsCategoryMaster>()
                                      .Where(p => !p.IsDeleted).ToListAsync();
```

I noticed by default the `Users` (`CreatedBy`) loaded with `AssetCategory`, and inside the `CreatedBy`, I can see `AssetsCategoryCreatedList` also loaded.

API call results in this error:

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles. Path: $.CreatedBy.AssetsCategoryCreatedList.CreatedBy.AssetsCategoryCreatedList.CreatedBy.AssetsCategoryCreatedList.CreatedBy.AssetsCategoryCreatedList.CreatedBy.AssetsCategoryCreatedList.CreatedBy.AssetsCategoryCreatedList.CreatedBy.AssetsCategoryCreatedList.CreatedBy.AssetsCategoryCreatedList.CreatedBy.AssetsCategoryCreatedList.CreatedBy.AssetsCategoryCreatedList.AssetCategoryName.......

The related entities are loaded without use of `.Include`. I m not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: [AutoInclude](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#model-configuration-for-auto-including-navigations)? [Lazy Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy)?

Comment: Check if you have [`UseLazyLoadingProxies`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy) call on db context setup. Or [`AutoInclude`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#model-configuration-for-auto-including-navigations) on corresponding entities.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderPetrov Thanks for your comments. No LazyLoadingProxies call on dbcontext setup. I added QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking in OnConfiguring the problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the below JSON serializer option as you want to ignore those `AssetsCategoryCreatedList`. This will ignore the circular reference and you will not get the above error. This is the way for ignoring circular references in System.Text.Json. More information is on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-6-0).

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new()
            {
                ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles            
            };
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

`Include` is used to eagerly load navigation properties. Without it, navigation properties will be loaded lazily only if the DbContext is configured to do so, eg by calling `UseLazyLoadingProxies` in the DbContext's configuration. When `AssetsCategoryMaster` gets serialized, the serializer will try to serialize the navigation properties at which point they'll be loaded.

If lazy loading isn't needed at all, `UseLazyLoadingProxies` should be removed.

If lazy loading is needed for other queries, one option is to disable tracking and thus lazy loading by using `AsNoTracking()` :

```
var AssetCategoryList = await _context.Set<AssetsCategoryMaster>()
                                      .AsNoTracking()
                                      .Where(p => !p.IsDeleted)
                                      .ToListAsync();
```

Another option, shown in the other answer, is to ignore circular references.

Comment: Hi @Panagiotis Kanavos Thanks for comment. As per your advise i used the below line and the issue resolved.                                                                                    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);

        }